# Render html with kotlin-react

Tags: frontend, kotlin-js

Been writing a lot of React with kotlin using the front end plugin.  It has been amazing thus far doing nothing overly exotic.  I am now trying to render stored HTML in my react component.

I am trying to use a plugin that has worked awesome writing regular react with no luck

```
@JsModule("react-render-html")
external fun renderHtml(html:String):ReactElement
```

Any ideas on how to do this, i wrote a cheap and easy parser to parse it but i wonder if there is a better way to use a library.

Answer (score 2):

was very easy....

```
@JsModule("html-react-parser")
external fun htmlReactParser(html: String):String
```

then was able to use it:

```
    section {
        +htmlReactParser(html = chosen.content)
    }
```